# Options on doing SOAP or REST with C++

Tags: c++, rest, soap

I am looking for an alternative to gSoap / Axis C to create a C++ soap client. So far I haven't been able to find anything other then those two projects. gSoap's license it a little too restrictive while Axis seems just about abandoned.

I also detect a generate trend in the industry away from SOAP towards REST which I battle to understand. SOAP makes so many things a lot easier while rest seems very pedestrian. Are there any elegant frameworks which let you do REST in an object oriented way in C/C++?

Comment: What kind of license would be acceptable? Does it have to be free?

Comment: Ideally yes. For what it does the functionality to send a bit of XML over TCP seems pretty straight forward. Languages like Java and .NET support this kind of stuff out of the box. Last time I check gSoap was around $1k per commercial application which is rather prohibitive for what it is.

Comment: I have fond memories of the days CORBA was the in-thing and ORBs were really expensive. Since then there were great efforts made by the open source community to free CORBA and provide it as open source. However since SOAP/WSDL, CORBA has large been become irrelevant, however there is little to integrate Java and C++ in the way CORBA allowed one to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's old, but it works: [`SPROXY.EXE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztta389h(v=vs.80).aspx).

> `SPROXY.EXE` is a command line tool that generates native C++ client code for accessing an XML Web service based on a WSDL description.

It's open source, you can [get it from CodePlex](http://atlserver.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Sproxy requires MSXML3. When faces with Windows one might as well use the full .NET stack. I am looking for a more generic solution which also would work on Linux etc.